# posting a file in binary format to the POST request URL in angular 7

Tags: angular, curl, http-post

Here, we have a curl command and we need to execute the same inside an angular application.

```
curl -X POST <url> --data-binary @<filenname>.dcm
```

Here is what we have done:
First we have uploaded the file :
HTML

```
<form>
<input type="file" class="inputFile" (change)="selectFileM($event)">
<button (click)="submit()">submit</button>
</form>
```

.ts file

```
selectFileM(event) {
    let snap;
    this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
    console.log(this.selectedFiles);
    const file = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
    console.log(file);
    this.currentFileUpload = new Fileup(file);
    console.log(this.currentFileUpload);
    this.userService.upload_orthanc(this.currentFileUpload).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
```

service:

```
    upload_orthanc(model) {
        let fd: FormData = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', model, model.name);
        var reader  = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsBinaryString(model);
        const a = reader.result;
        return this.http.post('https://trdorthanc.therightdoctors.com/instances', a, this.jwt());
      }
private jwt() {
      let headers = new Headers({'content-type': 'application/dicom' });
      return new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
  }
```

We are getting an error: 
ERROR TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsBinaryString' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

check the screenshot:
[image]

Please suggest some solution

Comment: What is your `Fileup`? Is it doing something to the file to make it not a blob?
Also, is a Filereader necessary or can you simply `this.http.post(formData)`

Answer (score 1):

readAsBinaryString(blob). In your case you didn't change the file to BLOB.

```
const modelData= new Blob([model], { type: "application/image" });
.
.
.
reader.readAsBinaryString(modelData);
```